SOLVED: Express.js static is serving css files just fine but not javascript files
I'm making a very simple Node application. I'm using CoffeeScript and Pug.
I used this code to set the static files:
app.use express.static('public')
This is my file tree:

This is working fine:
link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css")
As you can see here

But this is not:
script(src='/js/watch.js')
As you can see here

What have I done wrong?
SOLUTION:
I had a whitespace on the folder name


"CoffeeScript"... what a blast from the past. Any reason?

It's cleaner than JS and I don't like TS

What do the /* prefixes on the filenames mean? From a terminal, could you please [edit] your question to show the output of ls -l public/js (or dir if you're on Windows)?

server is sending the wrong mime-type

@JaromandaX that's because it's the default 404 page

@Phil - d'oh, of course :p

drwxr-xr-x 4 leftundersun leftundersun 4096 abr 19 00:23  .
drwxr-xr-x 7 leftundersun leftundersun 4096 abr 19 00:20  ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 leftundersun leftundersun 4096 abr 19 00:20  css
drwxr-xr-x 2 leftundersun leftundersun 4096 abr 19 00:23 'js '
OMG I HAD A SPACE ON THE FOLDER NAME
Thanks for the help, I lost like 3 hours trying to solve this

So, basically just typo (folder name)
